# ORACLE APEX web service p_body_blob

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

I am looking for a example that passes a json file in the request body to the apex_web_service.make_rest_request
Can someone please point me to an example ?

Thanks,
RD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to send files via **apex_web_service.make_rest_request**. In my examples I used an image file blob retrieved from table **SAMPLE_TABLE** column **BLOB_LOGO**.

#### option 1:

cache the file blob type directly from the query into a blob object and send it via **p_body_blob** parameter

```
DECLARE 
    obj_sample SAMPLE_TABLE%ROWTYPE;     
    file_blob blob;
    l_response clob;
BEGIN 
    -- query
    select * INTO obj_sample 
    from SAMPLE_TABLE where ID = 123;

    -- file as blob
    file_blob := obj_sample.BLOB_LOGO; 

    l_response   := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
        p_url           => 'url/to/api/',
        p_http_method   => 'POST',
        p_body_blob     => file_blob,
        p_proxy_override => 'url/to/proxy'
    );
    dbms_output.put_line(l_response);
END;
```

#### option 2:

first convert the file blob datatype into a base64 clob object and send it as json body (clob) via **p_body** parameter

```
DECLARE 
    obj_sample SAMPLE_TABLE%ROWTYPE; 
    json_sample clob; 
    file_clob clob;
    l_response clob;
BEGIN 
    -- query
    select * INTO obj_sample 
    from SAMPLE_TABLE where ID = 123;

    -- file as clob
    file_clob := apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(obj_sample.BLOB_LOGO); 
    json_sample := json_object(
        'SAMPLE_LOGO' value img_clob
    );

    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';
    l_response   := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
        p_url           => 'url/to/api/',
        p_http_method   => 'POST',
        p_body          => json_sample,
        p_proxy_override => 'url/to/proxy'
    );
    dbms_output.put_line(l_response);
END;
```

[docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aeapi/MAKE_REST_REQUEST-Function.html#GUID-C77BB45A-8968-470C-8243-BADB63743DE9)